# Launching firefox browser in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have added selenium jar files in eclipse mars .When I launched the firefox browser, I'm getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a free port
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.findFreePort(PortProber.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:326)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
    at Mypackage.Myfirstprogram.main(Myfirstprogram.java:10)
```

Comment: can you restart once and try?

Comment: @Anbarasan Can you consider showcasing your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Selenium standalone server uses port no 4444 by default. Make sure that this port is not being used by any other process. Kill any process that was running on that port number or use any other port number for selenium standalone server.